# Can I travel to Nepal from UAE with a Indian passport during the COVID situation

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-free-entry, covid-19, nepal

I am living in Dubai. I would like to know if I can travel to Nepal with my Indian passport without a visa in the COVID-19 situation directly from the UAE.

Answer (score 7):

**No, you can not travel. Nepal has blocked international and domestic flights.**

From the [Civil Aviation Authority of Nepal](http://caanepal.gov.np/news-detail/post/urgent-notice-about-extension-suspension-period-domestic-and-international-commercial-flights-2):

> [image: letter]

Assistive technology transcript:

> **URGENT NOTICE**
>
> To, All Domestic and International Airline Operators
>
> This is further to the Urgent Notice issued by this office with reference no. 2076/77 DDG2/D.No. 1717 dated 28th April 2020.
>
> As per the decision of Government of Nepal (Council of Ministers), the suspension period of all domestic and international commercial passenger flights has extended till 31 May 2020 (23:59 NST). Special permission from CAAN is required for Rescue flights, freighter flights and flights related to the medical and other essential supplies.
>
> Thanks for understanding the situation as usual.

Comment: This is 100% correct, but it's also worth noting that the suspension of flights has been being extended a week or two at a time since it was announced, and there's not presently any special reason to believe that flights will resume on June 1. (I was on what ended up being one of the last couple days of commercial flights out of Nepal, and at the time the suspension was announced, it was "only" through March 31.)